# Laravel Eloquent: Get First Item Collection in Collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to retrieve items based on certain conditions in a Laravel collection.

So, I have a collection of languages, each language has a collection of competitions. I want to fetch the still active competition based on `endAt`, if it doesn't exist then it must be `null`.

this is the collection i mean.

```php
$languages = $this->language->with('competitions')->get();

// RESULT:
// [
//     [
//         'name' => 'english',
//         'competitions' => [
//             [ 'endAt' => '...' ],
//             [ 'endAt' => '...' ],
//         ],
//     ],
//     [
//         'name' => 'indonesian',
//         'competitions' => [
//             [ 'endAt' => '...' ],
//             [ 'endAt' => '...' ],
//         ],
//     ]
// ];
```

I want to get a result like the following.

```php
[
    [
        'name' => 'english',
        'competitions' => null,
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'indonesian',
        'competitions' => [
           'endAt' => '...' 
        ],
    ]
];
```

I have tried this query, but it doesn't work.

```php
$languages = $this->language->whereHas('competitions', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->whereDate('endAt', '>=', Carbon::now());
})->get();
```